# Failed to apply delegate :TFlite crash in android

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

My app crashes when I am trying to use `tflite GPU`. I'm using `MoveNet` model from here [click](https://tfhub.dev/google/lite-model/movenet/singlepose/thunder/tflite/float16/4). I got no error in running this model in CPU.

Here is my interpreter initialization code.

```
            val compatList = CompatibilityList()


            val options = Interpreter.Options().apply{
                if(compatList.isDelegateSupportedOnThisDevice){
                    // if the device has a supported GPU, add the GPU delegate
                    val delegateOptions = compatList.bestOptionsForThisDevice
                    this.addDelegate(GpuDelegate(delegateOptions))
                } else {
                    // if the GPU is not supported, run on 4 threads
                    this.setNumThreads(8)
                }
            }
           interpreter = Interpreter(loadTFFile(),options)
```

gradle(module):

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.3.0'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.3.0'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.1.0'
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Failed to apply delegate: Following operations are not supported by GPU delegate:
    ARG_MAX: Operation is not supported.
    CAST: Operation is not supported.
    CONCATENATION: OP is supported, but tensor type isn't matched!
    DEQUANTIZE: 
    FLOOR_DIV: Operation is not supported.
    GATHER_ND: Operation is not supported.
    MUL: OP is supported, but tensor type isn't matched!
    PACK: Operation is not supported.
    RESHAPE: OP is supported, but tensor type isn't matched!
    SUB: OP is supported, but tensor type isn't.
```

I'm testing this on android 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code for delegation of tflite models and this is working.

```
tfliteModel = FileUtil.loadMappedFile(activity, this.getModelPath())
    tfliteOptions.setNumThreads(numThreads)
    tflite =
        try {
            val options = Interpreter.Options()
            options.addDelegate(NnApiDelegate())
            Interpreter(tfliteModel, options)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            try {
                val options = Interpreter.Options()
                options.addDelegate(GpuDelegate())
                Interpreter(tfliteModel, options)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                val options = Interpreter.Options()
                try {
                    Interpreter(tfliteModel, options)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    null
                }
            }
        }
```

this is in kotlin language

Comment: The example does not actually work, and has a subtle bug where there needs to be a `e.printStackTrace()` call after line 14 .  If the `GpuDelegate()` case throws an exception, it silently fails and returns an `Interpreter` with default `Interpreter.Options` (meaning no delegates).

Answer (score 0):

happened to me because i didn't add the following to Andorid Manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```